# Inserting the date into a table in word with VBA

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-word, ms-office

I am struggling to work out how to fix this code. Its Word 2007 VBA

It errors because the cell of the table is selected in its entirety rather than its contents i think.
Currently it's

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
    .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(2)
    .Rows(2).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    .Rows(2).Range.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleDot
    .Cell(2, 2).Range.InsertDateTime "yy.MM.dd", False, wdEnglishUK, wdCalendarWestern, False
End With
```

This creates a new row under the the first one and formats it to look nice but errors when trying to enter the date.
I have tried using the code in a keyboard enabled macro and it seems to work when I click in the cell but brings the same error when I highlight the whole cell (which lead me to suspect this was the problem)

Any ideas?

Comment: Got it working, thanks Tim!
it was just the ", False, wdEnglishUK, wdCalendarWestern, False" that caused the hiccup

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Sub tt()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
        .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=.Rows(2)
        With .Rows(2).Range
        .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleDot
        End With
        Set rng = .Cell(2, 2).Range
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        rng.InsertDateTime "yy.MM.dd" ', False, wdEnglishUK, wdCalendarWestern, False
    End With
End Sub
```

I find Word ranges hard to work with compared to Excel.  In particular Word table cells all have an "extra" character appended (which you can see if you turn on hidden formatting) which you have to work around.

Answer (score 0):

```
      .Cell(2, 2).Range.text = format(date, "yy.MM.dd")
```

This will give a number for the month - if you want 3 letters use 3 m's